# Returning the underlying enum value from a string gives error The type or namespace name 'enumType' could not be found

Tags: c#, dynamic, enums

I am trying to write a simple helper method which returns the underlying enum for a specified string representation of that enum!
This is the code I am writing at the moment

```
  public static dynamic GetEnum(Type enumType, string EnumValue)
    {
        return (enumType)Enum.Parse(enumType, EnumValue);
    }
```

I am getting

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'enumType' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Edited:
This is the finished method which was suggesed below:

```
    public static EnumType GetEnum<EnumType>(string EnumValue) where EnumType : struct
{
    EnumType result;
    Enum.TryParse<EnumType>(EnumValue, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast to a `Type` instance, but: you don't need to. In the case of `dynamic`, there is nothing to do: the value *already is* a boxed `EnumValue`:

```
return Enum.Parse(enumType, EnumValue);
```

However, generics might be a better approach here. You might want to look at the existing `TryParse<T>` method. This would be *instead of* using `Type`. `<T>` and `Type` don't play nicely together.

Comment: Thank you very Much i followed your second suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2):

I am using some extension method for the same please have a look

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(this string valueToParse) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            return EnumParse<T>(valueToParse);
        }

        private static T EnumParse<T>(object valueToParse) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            T defaultValue = default(T);

            if (valueToParse != null && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), valueToParse))
            {
                try
                {
                    return (T)valueToParse;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Enum.TryParse<T>(valueToParse.ToString(), out defaultValue);
                }
            }

            return defaultValue;
        }
```